# Localize numeric integers for different languages

Tags: swift, numberformatter

I needed to localize the numeric integers(like 1, 2, 3 etc) for different languages.

Like in arabic 2 would look like ٢

I used number formatter to achieve this and it seems to work fine for some languages:

```
var n = 02;
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
formatter.string(for: n);
```

This would give correct result as "٠٢"

Although when i change language to chinese or japanese. It doesn't work.
For chinese, japanese and many other languages it prints 02 only.

Then I dig out a little more and found out that replacing this one line would convert these integers to chinese:

```
formatter1.numberStyle = .spellOut
```

So now my code is something like

```
var n = 120;
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh_Hans_CN")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
formatter.string(for: n);
```

And it would print "一百二十" which is exactly what i want.

But the problem is when i use this spellOut with English, it prints One, Two like below code would result:

```
var n = 120;
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
formatter.string(for: n);
```

It would print "one hundred twenty" and not 120.

I am using this code to format the integers to the language set in the device. 
In the above examples I have hardcoded the locales but I am using device's language for this which works perfectly fine.

So in brief, the problem is how to convert these integers symbols to something that is native to device current language.

Comment: Unrelated: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 9 are THE [arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). `٠۱٢` and the others have indian origins

Comment: In Chinese, numerals are words and characters that denote the numbers. That's why `spellOut` works for that locale. The way to approach this is to have `switch` on the locale, if it uses the Hindu–Arabic numeral system or the East Asian one.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I am not just wondering about few languages like English, Arabic or Chinese. 
This question is generic.. given any language how do I convert the integers. 
Also how to check this locale related thing you mentioned?

Comment: Not directly related, but we Japanese does not prefer `百二十` when representing `120`. If you use something like this in ja_JP locale, your app would be reported as showing an odd behavior in Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn't support all numerals. You can see how numerals are represented in all supported locals using the following:

```
Locale.availableIdentifiers.forEach {
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: $0)
    print($0, ":", formatter.string(for: 1234567890)!)
}
```

Bear in mind that even if some locales gives a certain numerical system, the actual users of the app prefer to use another system.

Here is a way to use the `spellOut` number styling for East Asian locales:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans")
formatter.locale.regionCode

let spellOutLocales: Set = ["zh-Hant-TW",
                            "zh-Hant-MO",
                            "zh-Hant-HK",
                            "zh-Hant",
                            "zh-Hans-SG",
                            "zh-Hans-MO",
                            "zh-Hans",
                            "zh_Hant_HK",
                            "zh_Hans_CN",
                            "ja-JP",
                            "ko-KR",
                            "ko_KP",]

if spellOutLocales.contains(formatter.locale.identifier) {
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
} else {
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
}
```

`spellOutLocales` is not exhaustive.

And use it like so:

```
let n = 1234567890
formatter.string(for: n) //"十二亿三千四百五十六万七千八百九十"
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/number-formatting) a nice explanation of number formatting and internationalization.

---

Here is an example of expressing numbers using [Thai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_numerals) numerals:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "th_TH")
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let n = 1234567890
var str = formatter.string(for: n)! //"1,234,567,890" This is what the default formatter gives

let arabicNumerals = (0...9).map { String($0) }
let thaiNumerals = ["๐", "๑", "๒", "๓", "๔", "๕", "๖", "๗", "๘", "๙",]
let zipped = zip(arabicNumerals, thaiNumerals)

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)

zipped.forEach { (arabic, thai) in
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: arabic, options: .caseInsensitive)
    str = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str,
                                   options: .reportCompletion,
                                   range: range,
                                   withTemplate: thai)
}

print(str)  //๑,๒๓๔,๕๖๗,๘๙๐
```

What we did in the code above is replace the occurrences of Arabic numerals with the corresponding Thai ones. If the grouping separator should be avoided in the given locale then set `formatter.usesGroupingSeparator` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ran the above for loop and the thing is, it is still printing 1234567890 for almost all the languages. There are only 10-15 languages I think that show different symbols which can't be true right? About your solution, You have excluded 12 languages for spell out, does it means that only these 12 languages have different symbols? If no, then how do get this work for all the languages

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ran the above for loop and the thing is, it is still printing 1234567890 for almost all the languages. There are only 10-15 languages I think that show different symbols which can't be true right? About your solution, You have excluded 12 languages for spell out, does it means that only these 12 languages have different symbols? If no, then how do get this work for all the languages

Comment: @shivampokhriyal `spellOut` works only for some east Asian countries. In some cases, like [*Tamil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_numerals), there are more than 10 digits, and expressing numbers isn't so straightforward. Sticking to what Apple is using for numerals in each locale would be recommended. On another side, finding out what is the popular numeric system in each locale would be an accomplishment in itself, and that would require a lot of hard coding of numerals. I've added an example of doing so in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I think there should be a better way than using hardcoded regex for different languages. Nonetheless, I should just stick to the recommended way.

Comment: It may be best to just use localizable strings for `1234567890` and let the translator decide what is best representation for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
  
    var farsiNumbers: [String] {
        return ["۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"]
    }
    
    var arabicNumbers: [String] {
        return ["٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩"]
    }
    
    func transformNumbersToFarsi() -> String {
        var tempStr = self
        for (idx, char) in self.farsiNumbers.enumerated() {
            tempStr = tempStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(idx)", with: char, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: nil)
        }
        return tempStr
    }
    
    func transformNumbersToEng() -> String {
        var tempStr = self
        
        for (idx, char) in self.farsiNumbers.enumerated() {
            tempStr = tempStr.replacingOccurrences(of: char, with: "\(idx)", options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: nil)
        }
        
        for (idx, char) in self.arabicNumbers.enumerated() {
            tempStr = tempStr.replacingOccurrences(of: char, with: "\(idx)", options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: nil)
        }
        
        return tempStr
    }
    
    var isLatin: Bool {
        
        let upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        let lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        
        for c in self {
            if !upper.contains(c) && !lower.contains(c) {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    var isFarsi: Bool {
        
        //Remove extra spaces from the first and last word
        let value = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        if value == "" {
            return false
        }
        
        let farsiLetters = "آ ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ س ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ی ن و ه"
        let arabicLetters = " ء ا أ إ ء ؤ ئـ ئ آ اً ة ا ب ت ث ج ‌ ح خ د ذ ر ز س ‌ ش ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ك ل م ن ه و ى ڤ ي"
        for c in value {
            if !farsiLetters.contains(c) && !arabicLetters.contains(c) {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    var isBothLatinAndCyrillic: Bool {
        return self.isLatin && self.isFarsi
    }

}
```